# center *selected element* using css without destroying map continuity: dc.js

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I've not found a way to determine the selected element using crossfilter, dc.js, other than by using css.

My goal is to center the selected element in the viewing window, the following code achieves that aim, however, it does so by ripping it off of the larger map and positioning it in the center- that is **not** what I want.

Here is what it looks like, 
before selection:

[image]

after selection :

[image]

This is the code that executes this behaviour:

```
    /*highlight selected country*/
    g.selected path {
        stroke: yellow;
        stroke-width: 2px;
        fill: #ff69b4;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
```

How can I achieve this in a more reasonable way, such that the map remains together, and the selected element elegantly repositions itself to the center of the viewing partition?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this but I did find a demo that seems to be doing what you want: http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111116/pack-hierarchy.html

Comment: yeah but i think that one is not using crossfilter is it?

Comment: Okay, this is out of control. In the future please edit your original question instead of posting it three times. http://stackoverflow.com/q/32986945/676195

Comment: but- the nature of my attempts was evolving you know, so they're subtly different questions. I'm approaching it from different ways- but I think better to leave them up here because different programmers might see the task in one way- and another one different- you know what I mean? If you don't think so then I'll delete the others.